# Is this the correct way to escape quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm writing a laravel controller if that is relevant here.

`"\"$alias\""`

Here I am passing the variable in alias, and I want to surround it with double quotes.

`"\"remote\""`

Here I am just trying to pass the word remote enclosed in double quotes.

Not sure if I am doing this correctly, or if there is a better way to do it.

For the ones without variables, is `'"remote"'` a better way to achieve what I want?

Thanks again!

Comment: Have you actually tried any of this?

Comment: What are you escaping those strings for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "The value is \"$value\"";
```

and

```
echo 'The value is "'.$value.'"';
```

are both perfectly valid to show a variable in double quotes.

---

```
echo "The word is \"bird\"";
```

and

```
echo 'The word is "bird"';
```

are both perfectly valid to show a constant phrase in double quotes.

---

Remember that variables aren't parsed inside single-quoted strings, so `echo 'The value is $value';` won't work.

Comment: Why would you insist on the excessive syntax? Both PHP tags and braces are totally unnecessary for this example, yet there are too many PHP users already who believe that braces are required for the echo - so, better to omit them. Why show a bad example?

Comment: Why would you insist on undermining a new member who provided a perfectly reasonable answer? I'm aware brackets are not _required_ on echo statements, but I'm in the habit of using them as it often helps to neaten the code I'm writing. Is this wrong? Of course not. Editing an aleady-accepted answer just so that it conforms with one preference or another seems somewhat futile to me.

Comment: Yes, adding braces for echo is obviously wrong. They do no harm but braces have some certain meaning which inapplicable here. While your idea on using them just for decoration is wrong.

Comment: I understand that they are optional, and that the non-bracketed version is somtimes preferred because `echo` is not a function, but I still disagree completely that they are outright *wrong*. They do no harm (as correctly you said), they improve readability in some cases (which is significantly different from "decoration"), and PHP.net simply states "you are not required to use parentheses". I've better uses of my time that to be drawn into an argument on such a minor issue, I just wanted to make others reading this aware that `different != wrong`.

Comment: PHP.net is written by people and people sometimes go wrong. this phrasing, "you are not required to use parentheses" may be read as "parentheses *belongs* to echo syntax but optional" - which is wrong. in fact, you are just adding another operator to your code, out of nowhere. PHP users are already inclined to writing so much extra and useless code - why add another case? Not to mention that there is not a single reason to write your initial code as `<?php echo (...); ?>` as `<?=...?>` is enough.

Answer (score -1):

The above are incomplete and also incorrect, unnecessarily using brackets.

Not many people know how to properly use and output strings with PHP. Do it properly using inline strings, heredoc and nowdoc. The below may be incomplete so look at the PHP documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more info.

Single quotes (literal) will output exactly what you enter between them and cannot include escape characters or variables:

```
$a=1;
echo' "Double quoted" $a &#169; ';
//Output: "Double quoted" $a ©
```

Double quotes (inline) can include variables, escape characters, etc.

```
$a=1;
echo" 'Single quoted' $a &#169; \" escaped";
//Output: 'Single quoted' 1 © " escaped
```

Inline indexed variable:

```
echo "Index 2 of myvar: $myvar[2]";
echo "Index a of myvar: {$myvar['a']}";
```

Heredoc: (basically multi-line double quoted as above)

```
echo<<<myeot  //Start heredoc
'Single quoted text'
"Double quoted text"
The value of a is $a
The value of b[index] is {$b['index']}
myeot;       //end heredoc
```

Can also define variables with heredoc and nowdoc:

```
$str=<<<myeot
xxx
Number $a will output
yyy
myeot;
```

Nowdoc is very similar to heredoc but is supported by PHP 5.3.0 and above only.